# Connect to http authenticated website

Tags: c#, webclient

I have this code, trying to get data from this a website secured with HTTP authentication, and it just halts the program on the DownloadString function.  If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, I would be grateful for help

```
string url = "http://example.com/passwordprotected";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        Console.Write("starting");
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "pass");
        Console.WriteLine("before");
        string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
        Console.WriteLine("after");
        //Debug.Write(htmlCode);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(htmlCode);
        Console.Write("done");
    }
```

I know the url is correct, because I can access it in person.

Comment: Did you try setting `client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;`?

Comment: It "halts the program"? Can you be more specific? Are you getting a run-time error? `DownloadString()` waits for the download to complete before execution finishes, so perhaps that's what you're seeing?

Comment: mason, you're solution fixed the problem immediately!  I just added that and it works!  Thank you

Comment: @mason should probably add that as answer with some explanation so OP can accept ;)

Comment: @user3413723 If you use the "@mason" to ping me, then it'll notify me that you've replied. Otherwise I won't get the notification. Luckily Luke pinged me.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials=false;
```

Otherwise it won't actually use the specified credentials. [MSN describes how to use this property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx) properly.